# Tar Compressed command output to curl

Tags: curl, tar

I want to share the output of tar compressed image to curl as an input.

I am unsuccessful with the following command.

```
tar -cvf - -C filedir ./ | gzip > - | curl -d @- -T compressedfile.tar.gz tftp://<ip>/file > compressedfile.tar.gz
```

My intention is avoid creating the intermediate compressed image (compressedfile.tar.gz) in the system then upload the compressed image using curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
tar --create --file=- --directory=/dir1 ./ | gzip -c |
curl -T- tftp://192.168.20.10/gzipimage.tar.gz
```

(split in two lines for readability)

curl's `-T` option can read the uploaded file from stdin when '-' is used instead of file name. But when so, it has no file name to append to the URL so you better set the full name in the URL you're uploading to.